# How to declare generic property that accept only extension of some class in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can I declare something like that:

```
private componentsArr: <T extends Component>[];
```

So i can push objects that extends Component class to componentsArr

Edit: I have another problem

Here are screenshot:

[image: Generic type problem]

[image: Problem description]

What im doing worng?

Comment: Generally not ok to change the topic of a question after you asked it, and remove the answer mark because you changed the content of the question. Ask another question ..

Comment: Changed the answer to reflect the new question,

Comment: Sure, sorry. I am not able to ask another question until 90 minutes so i edited this.

Comment: Ok, I did not know about this limitation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the type constraint at the point where you declare `T`. If `T` is a class type parameter you can write it like this. For the method you need to constrain the parameter type to be derived from `T` not directly from `Component` because the compiler need to know that the argument type can be assigned to `T` in order to add it to the array:

```
class MyClass<T extends Component> {
    private componentsArr: T[]
    addComponent<TSub extends T>(c: new () => TSub): TSub {
        const newComponent = new c(); 
        this._components.push(newComponent); 
        return newComponent; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `public addComponent<TSub extends T>(c: new () => TSub): TSub `